# How to send an HTML file, then once requested by the client, send a different one?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, http, socket.io

*Note: I am using node.js, express.js, and socket.io.*

I am trying to create a web page that, when a user connects, will display from one .html page (called **homepage.html**), but upon request, a different .html file (called **lobby.html**) will be sent to be displayed.

So my question is: How can I send one .html file initially, and then upon request, send a different one?

**server.js** -

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

http.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/homepage.html');
});
```

This successfully sends my **homepage.html** to the client browser to be displayed. However, I want to be able to send an entirely different .html file in response to a client request. Am I on the right track by including something like the following in my **homepage.html** file...

```
app.get('lobby', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + 'lobby.html');
}
```

...and then in my **server.js***, add something like...

```
let http = require('http');

const options = {
    hostname: "/",
    port: 3000,
    method: "GET"
}

const req = https.request(options, res => {
    ; // How do I display the response .html file?
});

// when a button or something is clicked, request
// lobby.html
req.write();

req.end();
```

Thank you very much for the help!

Eric

Comment: "So my question is: How can I send one .html file initially, and then upon request, send a different one?" - if you mean sending two HTML files in response to a single quest, then no, you can't. That's not how HTTP works.

Comment: What do you mean by "client request", exactly? There's no distinction between the first GET request or the second GET request from a browser.

Comment: @Dai what I meant was one request (the connecting to the server) gets one HTML file, and then a separate request gets the other HTML file.

Comment: Yes, but a request for what? Is your example with `lobby.html` meant to be an example or do you actually have a file called `lobby.html`? And is that the file you want to serve in response to a request for `/lobby`?

Comment: @Dai maybe I am not understanding something, but I am trying to basically have a two page website. Do I have to navigate them to a different url or something? Like from http:websitename.com/homepage to http:websitename.com/lobby? Or can I just have them be on a dynamic http:websitename.com where if they press certain buttons, different html files will be displayed?

Comment: First off, thanks for the comments! And to answer your question, yes the /lobby.html is what I want to serve in response to a request for /lobby.

Comment: To do things properly (without violating the semantics of HTTP and the web) then yes, they'd have to navigate to a different URL (e.g. `/lobby` to get served `lobby.html`). You *can* serve different content in response to a request for `/` by (for example) looking at the HTTP method (e.g. GET vs POST and querystring values) but I strongly recommend against doing this because POST should not be used to serve content unless it's a validation error page).

Comment: @Eric if you want a two-page website  then you need to  use `routing`  and that's what you are using so what do you want now?

Comment: Oh okay, that makes sense. So I just have to navigate them to a new URL--got it. Thanks! Would you want to post that as a response or something so I can accept it (I'm new to stack overflow and don't really know what is expect of me here...).

Comment: @kedar sedai - I guess that is what I am trying to do, I just wanted to make sure. Thanks for your comment!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Yes the `/lobby.html` is what I want to serve in response to a request for `/lobby`.

Then just change your `server.js` to this (i.e. add new `get` mapping):

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

http.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/homepage.html');
});

app.get('/lobby', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/lobby.html');
});
```